# Отображение сторон куба под разным углом

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Я создал куб, вроде всё ок, но некоторые его стороны под определенным  углом не отображаются. В чем может быть дело?

```
public class Main extends SimpleApplication {

    public static float PIXELSMOVED_TO_RADIANSROTATED = 0.01f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        app.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        visual();
        moveMyFuckingGeometryWithMouse(createFuckingCube());
    }

    Geometry[] createFuckingCube() {
        Geometry[] geometry = new Geometry[6];
        //Первая сторона
        Vector3f[] frontVertices = new Vector3f[4];
        frontVertices[0] = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);//нижняя левая вершина
        frontVertices[1] = new Vector3f(3, 0, 0);//нижняя правая вершина
        frontVertices[2] = new Vector3f(0, 3, 0);//верхняя левая вершина
        frontVertices[3] = new Vector3f(3, 3, 0);//верхняя правая вершина    
        //Вторая сторона
        Vector3f[] leftVertices = new Vector3f[4];
        leftVertices[0] = new Vector3f(0, 0, -3);//нижняя левая вершина
        leftVertices[1] = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);//нижняя правая вершина
        leftVertices[2] = new Vector3f(0, 3, -3);//верхняя левая вершина
        leftVertices[3] = new Vector3f(0, 3, 0);//верхняя правая вершина
        //Третья сторона
        Vector3f[] rightVertices = new Vector3f[4];
        rightVertices[0] = new Vector3f(3, 0, 0);//нижняя левая вершина
        rightVertices[1] = new Vector3f(3, 0, -3);//нижняя правая вершина
        rightVertices[2] = new Vector3f(3, 3, 0);//верхняя левая вершина
        rightVertices[3] = new Vector3f(3, 3, -3);//верхняя правая вершина
        //Четвертая сторона
        Vector3f[] bottomVertices = new Vector3f[4];
        bottomVertices[0] = new Vector3f(0, 0, -3);//нижняя левая вершина
        bottomVertices[1] = new Vector3f(3, 0, -3);//нижняя правая вершина
        bottomVertices[2] = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);//верхняя левая вершина
        bottomVertices[3] = new Vector3f(3, 0, 0);//верхняя правая вершина
        //Пятая сторона
        Vector3f[] topVertices = new Vector3f[4];
        topVertices[0] = new Vector3f(0, 3, 0);//нижняя левая вершина
        topVertices[1] = new Vector3f(3, 3, 0);//нижняя правая вершина
        topVertices[2] = new Vector3f(0, 3, -3);//верхняя левая вершина
        topVertices[3] = new Vector3f(3, 3, -3);//верхняя правая вершин
        //Шестая сторона
        Vector3f[] backsideVertices = new Vector3f[4];
        backsideVertices[0] = new Vector3f(0, 0, -3);//нижняя левая вершина
        backsideVertices[1] = new Vector3f(3, 0, -3);//нижняя правая вершина
        backsideVertices[2] = new Vector3f(0, 3, -3);//верхняя левая вершина
        backsideVertices[3] = new Vector3f(3, 3, -3);//верхняя правая вершин
        //Сетим геометрию и отправляем её
        geometry[0] = createSide(frontVertices, ColorRGBA.Blue);
        geometry[1] = createSide(leftVertices, ColorRGBA.Red);
        geometry[2] = createSide(rightVertices, ColorRGBA.Green);
        geometry[3] = createSide(bottomVertices, ColorRGBA.Gray);
        geometry[4] = createSide(topVertices, ColorRGBA.Yellow);
        geometry[5] = createSide(backsideVertices, ColorRGBA.Brown);


        return geometry;
    }

    void moveMyFuckingGeometryWithMouse(final Geometry[] geometry) {
        //вращение куба  

        inputManager.addMapping("MouseButton", new MouseButtonTrigger(MouseInput.BUTTON_LEFT));
        //    inputManager.addMapping("pizds", new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_WHEEL, true));
        //слушатель мыши 
        inputManager.addListener(new AnalogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnalog(String name, float value, float tpf) {
                float centredY = inputManager.getCursorPosition().y - 0.5f * settings.getHeight();
                float centredX = inputManager.getCursorPosition().x - 0.5f * settings.getWidth();
                Quaternion quat = new Quaternion();
                quat.fromAngles(PIXELSMOVED_TO_RADIANSROTATED * centredY, PIXELSMOVED_TO_RADIANSROTATED * centredX, 0);
                for (Geometry geom : geometry) {
                    geom.setLocalRotation(quat);
                }
            }
        }, "MouseButton");


    }

    void visual() {
        flyCam.setEnabled(false);//передвижение по миру отменяем 
        //Применяется фильтр обнаружения края мультипликационного стиля для всех объектов в сцене.
        FilterPostProcessor fpp = new FilterPostProcessor(assetManager);
        fpp.addFilter(new CartoonEdgeFilter());
        viewPort.addProcessor(fpp);
    }

    Geometry createSide(Vector3f[] Vertices, ColorRGBA color) {
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        int[] frontIndexes = {2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2};
        mesh.setBuffer(Type.Position, 3, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(Vertices));
        mesh.setBuffer(Type.Index, 3, BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(frontIndexes));
        mesh.updateBound();
        Geometry geometry = new Geometry("OurMesh", mesh); // using our custom mesh object
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
                "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        mat.setColor("Color", color);
        geometry.setMaterial(mat);
        rootNode.attachChild(geometry);
        return geometry;
    }
}
```

Comment: каким методом удаляете невидимые линии?

Comment: извините, но я не понял вашего вопроса

Comment: есть разные методы скрывать невидимые линии, чаще всего используют метод z-буфера

Comment: а можно точнее?

Comment: http://compgraph.tpu.ru/zbuffer.htm

Comment: http://100byte.ru/mxscrptxmpls/zbffr/zbffr.html

Comment: ну как успехи?  решил проблему?

Comment: да, суть была в другом
нужно было в противоположно порядке указать вершины треугольников, из которых состоят 2д квадраты для нашего куба
 int[] frontIndexes = {2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2};  -- вот этот кусок нужно изменить

Comment: но спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было в противоположном порядке указать вершины треугольников, из которых состоят 2д квадраты для нашего куба
   int[] frontIndexes = {2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2};

-- вот этот кусок нужно изменить, вот код создающий квадраты с нужной мне видимостью в зависимости от выбора:

```
Geometry createSide(Vector3f[] Vertices, ColorRGBA color, boolean side) {
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    int[] frontIndexes = {2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2};
    int[] backsideVertices = {2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2};
    int[] visualSide;
    if (side) {
        visualSide = frontIndexes;
    } else {
        visualSide = backsideVertices;
    }

    mesh.setBuffer(Type.Position, 3, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(Vertices));
    mesh.setBuffer(Type.Index, 3, BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(visualSide));
    mesh.updateBound();
    Geometry geometryOfSide = new Geometry("OurMesh", mesh); // using our custom mesh object
    Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
            "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
    mat.setColor("Color", color);
    geometryOfSide.setMaterial(mat);
    rootNode.attachChild(geometryOfSide);
    return geometryOfSide;
}
```